# Creating custom network listner for Retrofit Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am using retofit service without using callback. So, its probably going with Kotlin Coroutine `suspend fun`. I referred many blogs, mediums and so many tutorials. Well this is easy to get response using coroutine `scope` with `IO and Main` thread.

So, after referring some examples I am considers to do code like this:

Restrofit Service Interface `RetrofitInterfaces.kt`:

```
interface RetrofitInterfaces {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("get-videos-pagination")
    suspend fun getTemplates(@Field("app_name") app_name: String,
                             @Field("sort_by") sortBy: String,
                             @Field("video_loaded_ids") loadedIds: String): Response<Model_Video_List>
}
```

Where `Model_Video_List.kt` class is my response data class.

Retrofit Builder `RetrofitClient.kt`:

```
object RetrofitClient {
    fun makeRetrofitService(mContext: Context): RetrofitInterfaces {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppPreferences.getBaseUrl(mContext) + "/api/v3/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build().create(RetrofitInterfaces::class.java)
}
}
```

Here I am using `Gson` to `serialise` or `deserialise` `Json data`.

Now what is problematic and where problem started in to get error response I am using `ResultWrapper.kt`:

```
class ResultWrapper {
    enum class ErrorCode {
        NETWORK,// Connection failed or timeout
        SERVER,// Server errors due to maintenance or over request
        INVALID// Response is success but can't serialised with Data Class!
    }

    interface ResponseWrapper {
        suspend fun onSuccess(response: Response<Any>)

        suspend fun onFailure(eCode: ErrorCode)
    }

    private var responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper? = null
        set

    suspend fun enqueue(response: Response<Any>, responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper) {
        this.responseWrapper = responseWrapper
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            responseWrapper.onSuccess(response)
        } else {
            val errorCode = response.code()
            when (errorCode) {
                in 200..299 -> {
                    responseWrapper.onFailure(ErrorCode.INVALID)
                }
                in 400..499 -> {
                    responseWrapper.onFailure(ErrorCode.NETWORK)
                }
                in 500..599 -> {
                    responseWrapper.onFailure(ErrorCode.SERVER)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, now I can call this `enqueue fun` from anywhere in `app` like:

```
private fun getVideoList(loadedIds: String, sortBy: String) {
    val service = RetrofitClient.makeRetrofitService(mContext)
    scope.launch {
        val response = service.getTemplates("MyApp", sortBy, loadedIds)
        val resultWrapper = ResultWrapper()
        resultWrapper.enqueue(response, object : ResultWrapper.ResponseWrapper {
            override suspend fun onSuccess(response: Response<Any>) {

            }

            override suspend fun onFailure(eCode: ResultWrapper.ErrorCode) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

But I am getting `compile error` for passing `response` in `resultWrapper.enqueue()` because in `ResultWrapper.ResponseWrapper interface` there is method defined with `suspend fun onSuccess(response: Response<Any>)`. So, type conversion problem occurred here!

If Retrofit `CallBack<T>` can handle any type of `Model or Data classes` and return which is exact tpyed. Like above service requires `Model_Video_List` class in response and other services requires there own then what to do for it? Is there only way to use separate function for every service? Or is it only possible in Java?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce a generic parameter type `T` in your class `ResultWrapper`, so whenever you create an instance of this class you must specify an actual type in place of `T`.

Change your `ResultWrapper` to this:

```
class ResultWrapper<T> {
    enum class ErrorCode {
        NETWORK,// Connection failed or timeout
        SERVER,// Server errors due to maintenance or over request
        INVALID// Response is success but can't serialised with Data Class!
    }

    interface ResponseWrapper<T> {
        suspend fun onSuccess(response: Response<T>)

        suspend fun onFailure(eCode: ErrorCode)
    }

    private var responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper<T>? = null
        set

    suspend fun enqueue(response: Response<T>, responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper<T>) {
        this.responseWrapper = responseWrapper
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            responseWrapper.onSuccess(response)
        } else {
            val errorCode = response.code()
            when (errorCode) {
                in 200..299 -> {
                    responseWrapper.onFailure(ErrorCode.INVALID)
                }
                in 400..499 -> {
                    responseWrapper.onFailure(ErrorCode.NETWORK)
                }
                in 500..599 -> {
                    responseWrapper.onFailure(ErrorCode.SERVER)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also change your method to this:

```
private fun getVideoList(loadedIds: String, sortBy: String) {
    val service = RetrofitClient.makeRetrofitService(mContext)
    scope.launch {
        val response = service.getTemplates("MyApp", sortBy, loadedIds)
        val resultWrapper = ResultWrapper<Model_Video_List>()
        resultWrapper.enqueue(response, object : ResultWrapper.ResponseWrapper<Model_Video_List> {
            override suspend fun onSuccess(response: Response<Model_Video_List>) {

            }

            override suspend fun onFailure(eCode: ResultWrapper.ErrorCode) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I can't imagine this type of work done in kotlin also :)