# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 6 column 17 path $.ErrMsgDtl

Tags: android, kotlin

Getting JsonSyntax Exception while parsing data from server. I checked my model class and server response. It looks good to me. Any idea how to resolve this issue? Error says expected string but was begin_object. Dont know where i am doing wrong.
Below is response from server

```
 {
        "Data": {
            "Transactions": [
                {
                    "Earns": [
                        {
                            "Description": "",
                            "EarnId": "46723912",
                            "Earned": 10000.0
                        }
                    ],
                    "Expires": "2021-12-31 00:00:00",
                    "Store": "QATes",
                    "StoreTrans": "107884927",
                    "TranDate": "2021-02-01 12:26:34"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Status": "SUCCESS",
        "ErrCde": null,
        "ErrMsg": null,
        "ErrMsgDtl": null
    }
```

Below is my Model class

```
class BonusSummaryDataResponse {
        @SerializedName("Transactions")
        var transactions: ArrayList<BonusTransData>? = null

        class BonusTransData {
            @SerializedName("Earns")
            var earns: ArrayList<BonusEarnsData>? = null

            @SerializedName("Expires")
            var expires: String? = null

            @SerializedName("Store")
            var store: String? = null

            @SerializedName("StoreTrans")
            var storeTrans: String? = null

            @SerializedName("TranDate")
            var tranDate: String? = null
        }

        class BonusEarnsData {
            @SerializedName("Description")
            var description: String? = null

            @SerializedName("EarnId")
            var earnId: String? = null

            @SerializedName("Earned")
            var earned: Double = 0.0
        }

}

ResponseWrapper

data class ResponseWrapper<T>(
        @SerializedName("Data")
        var data: T?,
        @SerializedName("Status")
        val status: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("ErrCde")
        val errorCode: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("ErrMsg")
        val errorMessage : String? = null,
        @SerializedName("ErrMsgDtl")
        val errorMessageDetail: String?= null)
```

Like below we are calling the function:

```
 @POST("services/abc/summary")
    fun getBonusCashSummary(@Body tBonusSummaryRequest: BonusSummaryRequest): 
 Observable<ResponseWrapper<BonusSummaryDataResponse>>
```

Above ResponseWrapper is the generic class where we are passing BonusSummaryDataResponse data class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473668/creating-custom-network-listner-for-retrofit-kotlin-coroutine

Comment: null is not a string I think.I don't know much about it but using null as "null" is a string